# how can I arrange the extensions by date or enabled and disabled

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, browser-addons

my chrome or firefox addons are a mess 
I can't deal with it which are on which are off is there a way to arrange them
in chrome and firefox.

Comment: In Firefox about:addons shows which extensions are disabled or enabled. Enabled are shown first.

Comment: and chrome?  and also i need it to be arranged alphabetically